# Retrieving autoincrement value in Snowflake SQL Scripting?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I retrieve the autoincrement value just after an insert in snowflake using sql scripting?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MY_TABLE(TOTO STRING, NEWID BIGINT AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$

BEGIN

  INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(TOTO) VALUES ('HELLO WORLD');

  RETURN 12345; // how do I get the last NEWID?

END;

$$;
```

Comment: Hi , one way could be ge the Max, select max (NEWID)  from MY_TABLE

Comment: Yes but this is not 100% guaranteed to return the correct value.
If someone else inserts a record between my insert and my select, I sould get the latest value, not mine

Comment: Maybe I should just not use AUTOINCREMENT and use a SEQUENCE instead. Might be simpler...

Comment: It depends, how you want to insert the value, if  you use AUTOINCREMENT, then when inserting you don't have to specify the column name, also there is no guarantee that what you could get by using Sequence will also be the latest value as some one might have inserted between your retrieval and the data displayed ....

Comment: Nope because I'll first get the value of the next sequence and then only use that value in the INSERT statement. Should be fine

Answer (score 2):

- [EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate#examples)
- [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-sequence)
- [RESULT_SCAN()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan)
- [LAST_QUERY_ID()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_query_id)

[image]

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE SEQ_INCREMENT;
 CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MY_TABLE(TOTO STRING, NEWID BIGINT DEFAULT SEQ_INCREMENT.NEXTVAL NOT NULL);
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE execute_immediate_local_variable()
RETURNS INT
AS
 $$
 DECLARE
    v1 VARCHAR DEFAULT 'DESC SEQUENCE SEQ_INCREMENT';
    result INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(TOTO) VALUES ('HELLO WORLD');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v1; 
    result := ( SELECT $4-1 FROM table(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID(-1))) );
    RETURN result;
 END;
$$;
CALL execute_immediate_local_variable();
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
```

If you look at the auto increment query plan we see snowflake accessing "getNextVal_null".NEXTVAL ... the _null part is the SEQUENCE that's autogenerated by the auto increment. But I couldn't work out how to access this -> so approached the problem with the SEQUENCE instead of auto increment.

I also had to use the last_query_id() function so not to increment the sequence when evaluating it, hence the -1 is applied to the next_val (this is referenced via $4).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a similar answer, although maybe a little bit simpler

The stored proc below inserts a new record and returns the ID
The "trick" I used is to collect the new sequence Id into a variable rather than setting it as a default on the database column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AUDIT.JOB_INSERT_PROC (JOB_TYPE    STRING)
RETURNS BIGINT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS 
$$
DECLARE 
  JOB_ID DEFAULT ( SELECT JOB_ID_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL );
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO AUDIT.JOB(JOB_ID, JOB_TYPE)
      VALUES(:JOB_ID, :JOB_TYPE);

  RETURN :JOB_ID;
END;
$$
```

Thanks for your help.
Really appreciated